# Regex to extract usernames prefixed with @ excluding nested usernames and symbols

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to extract usernames from strings but some of the edge cases I can't seem to handle.

Ideal outputs where the list on the right is the matches:

```
No matches here -> []
Hello @user123 -> [@user123]
Hello @user123 @user1234 -> [@user123, @user1234]
Hi @user1, meet @user2. @user3. -> [@user1, @user2, @user3]
Invalid @user@123 -> []
@user -> [@user]
.@user -> []
@user.123 -> []
"" -> []
No input -> []
https://www.example.com/@user123 -> []
hello@example.com -> []
<@U12345678> -> []
```

https://regex101.com/r/oe4MGR/1 this is the best I have so far using `(?:^| )@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` but it doesn't handle some of the edge cases, I will doing the extraction in Golang but the actual code isn't quite as important as the regex string.

```
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?:^| )@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`)
    matches := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(inputField, -1)
```

Comment: How does this input work?`@user.123 -> []`. It should return @user ryt? Similar to `user2` and `user3` in this `Hi @user1, meet @user2. @user3. -> [@user1, @user2, @user3]`?

Comment: On the first group, instead of check only for space, you can check for symbols. For example, check for all that are not valid for name: `(?:^|([^a-zA-Z0-9\r\n]))@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`. At the end, you need to remove the character before @

Comment: If you don't what to capture the character before the @, you can use Negative Lookbehind (`(?<!YOUR_REGEX_EXPRESSION)` that is supported by python: `(^|(?<![a-zA-Z0-9\r\n]))@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

Comment: Why do you tag both `go` and `python`? Your requirement isn't possible with Go's regex alone because of the lack of support for lookarounds, but can be easily done with Python's regex.

Comment: You should never use the regex tested in Python `re` inside Go code without more testing since RE2 is far from `re`. You can't use a lot of constructs in RE2, e.g. lookarounds. It is not clear what you want to match in that regex fiddle of yours, please edit and share a clear regex fiddle, with two groups of strings, those that you want to match and those you don't.

Answer (score -2):

I tried `"(^| )(@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)( |$|, |. |,$|.$)"` and `"(^| )(@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)[,.]?( |$)"`, but both of them not work as expected.
One solution is use a function:

```py
import re
from functools import reduce
import operator
from typing import List

ss = '''
No matches here -> []
Hello @user123 -> [@user123]
Hello @user123 @user1234 -> [@user123, @user1234]
Hi @user1, meet @user2. @user3. -> [@user1, @user2, @user3]
Invalid @user@123 -> []
@user -> [@user]
.@user -> []
@user.123 -> []
"" -> []
No input -> []
https://www.example.com/@user123 -> []
hello@example.com -> []
<@U12345678> -> []
'''


def find_them(s: str) -> List[str]:
    p = '(@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)[,.]?'
    re0 = f'^{p} '
    re1 = f' {p} '
    re2 = f' {p}$'
    re3 = f'^{p}$'
    return list(reduce(operator.add, [re.findall(rgx, s) for rgx in (re0, re1, re2, re3)]))


def test():
    for line in ss.strip().splitlines():
        a, b = line.split(' -> ')
        rs = find_them(a)
        assert '[' + ', '.join(rs) + ']' == b.strip(), a
    print('Pass test~')


def demo():
    s = 'Hello @user123'
    print(find_them(s))
    # ['@user123']
    s = 'Hello @user123 @user1234'
    print(find_them(s))
    # ['@user123', '@user1234']
    s = 'Hi @user1, meet @user2. @user3.'
    print(find_them(s))
    # ['@user1', '@user2', '@user3']
    s = '@user'
    print(find_them(s))
    # ['@user']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Comment: The problem here is the examples are just test cases and not a real input as one big string, we just expect a string and expect the outputs

Comment: @lleewwiiss you can use the `find_them` function.